# Is there any pure html way to "combine" markup tags into custom one?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if I can make something like:

```
<myTag>myAwesomText</myTag>
```

While "myTag" is a combination of other html tags, example:

```
<div class="myClass">
<p>myAwesomText</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In short: No, you cannot. You could for example create Knockout.js components or template binding to achieve what you want. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the answer is no, this is not possible in HTML.

Usually your text editor (for example Sublime Text) has an option to create snippets where you can customise a shortcut like `<myTag>` in which custom HTML or any code can be inserted. If you are interested in this, see [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com) and [Their Snippet Feature](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html)

Note: you could also use a functional language like Javascript to create a feature like this

Also, a hacky way of doing something similar to this is creating a custom html element and using css to modify its properties (*although I'm sure this isn't widely supported*):

```css
mytag {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<mytag>This is bold and red</mytag>
```

Comment: "a hacky way" — It is important to note that inventing your own markup and styling it is not the same as using real elements. They are likely to be treated differently by tools which don't just render elements visually (such as screen readers and search engines).

Comment: Completely agree, as I said it is most definitely not supported widely and shouldn't be used even if it is a hacky way to 'create' a custom element

Comment: Already checked this option, even if it is not recommended it only allows styling not "combining" tags.